# How to make release build with tests for flavor?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have two flavors in build.gradle: 'distribution' and 'staging'. Distribution flavor should create market-ready APK without debugging tools and tests. And here is no problem.

Staging flavor should contains tests from androidTest directory. Possibly this is simple task but I can't find a solution how to achieve it.

How to include androidTest into APK for specified flavor?

Comment: androidTest folder is used to execute test with android instrumentation test framework.
You don't have to manually put the folder in the APK, it will end in the test apk by default if you setup your project and follow this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests

Comment: @MatPag Of course I know it. I mean how to enable tests for APK only for specified flavor?

Comment: In this case you need to launch the specific task by hand. Usually the instrumented test are mapped to a task called `:app:connectedCheck`, You can find the other task in the Gradle right panel in AS, in the "verification" category. 
Here you should be able to find other gradle tasks and some of them should specify the flavor to limit the instrumented test to that one. Something like `connected{YOUR_FLAVOR}DebugAndroidTest`, try to launch it by command line and see what happens